# SQL Server - Join two tables based on most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

```
       A
---------------
No.    Name
1      J.Smith
2      R.Alan
3.     D.Williams


       B
----------------------------
ID.    Date        Address    No.(FK from table A) 
1      10/03/01   blah blah   1
2      08/02/05   blah blah   2
3.     12/01/02   blah blah   3
4.     03/07/11   blah blah   1
5.     30/03/09   blah blah   2
```

I want to join the two tables together ommiting rows with duplicate names based on the most recent date from table B. For example, if I join table A and B together using a left inner join, I will get two rows for J. Smith (based on rows 1 and 4 from table B). I would like to exclude the one with the older date (row 1 from table B).

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I need to include all columns from table B.

Comment: What date is `10/03/01`? `2010-March-01`? `Oct-03-2001`? `10-March-2001`? `10-March-1901`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblB.[No] ORDER BY tblB.[Date]) AS RowNbr,
        tblB.*
    FROM
        B AS tblB
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A AS tblA
    LEFT JOIN CTE
        ON tblA.No=CTE.No
        AND CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH [max_dates] AS (
    SELECT [No], MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
    FROM [TableB]
    GROUP BY [No]
)
SELECT [a].[Name], [b].[Date]
FROM [TableA] AS [a]
JOIN [max_dates] AS [b] ON ([a].[No] = [b].[No])
ORDER BY [a].[No] ASC
```

Comment: One downside is that if you need any other data from B it must go into the CTE or B needs to link into the SELECT statement in addition. Certainly works for the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.No 
     , A.Name
     , C.Date
     , C.Address
     , C. ...
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT Address , ... , No, Date,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY No ORDER BY Date DESC) AS row
        FROM B 
    ) C ON A.No = C.No 
WHERE C.row = 1

WHERE COALESCE(C.row, 1) = 1 [if there is no link ,and you'll get Date NULL]
```

edit: if you have a lot of columns in B

```
SELECT A.No 
     , A.Name
     , C.* (also row)
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT * ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY No ORDER BY Date DESC) AS row
        FROM B 
    ) C ON A.No = C.No 
WHERE C.row = 1
```

Comment: Ok so this seems to work BUT what if table B has other columns that I want to include in my sql statement that aren't needed in the partition?

Comment: you can do the partition by No order by Date and get all IDs  and with these you get all the data you need from table B, and after, you can make the join with table A

Comment: In reality table B has many other columns (Address for example). How do I include the non partitioned columns in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Nice use of the CTE by Rory Hunter, alternatively without it:

```
 SELECT [A].Name, [B].Date
 FROM [A]
     INNER JOIN [B]
         INNER JOIN
         ( -- build a limitation on B
             SELECT No, MaxDate = Max(Date)
             FROM [B]
             GROUP BY No
         ) BLimit
            ON BLimit.No = B.No
            AND BLimit.MaxDate = B.Date
         ON B.No = A.No
```

BLimit acts as limiter by only allowing the highest date to come through only for each No (FK). And all fields from B can be used for the query as the limitation happens on B only using BLimit.